# Add tag synonyms for [relation] on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, tag-synonyms, synonym-request

**Synonym-Request:** There are several tags on Stack Overflow which *could* be synonyms of [relation](/questions/tagged/relation).

---

I propose that the primary tag be [relation](/questions/tagged/relation) (or perhaps [relationship](/questions/tagged/relationship)):

- [relation](/questions/tagged/relation) with 84 questions currently

[From Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/relation): a noun whose second definition (probably the most relevant) is:

> an aspect or quality (as resemblance) that connects two or more things
>   or parts as being or belonging or working together or as being of the
>   same kind ; specifically : a property
>   (as one expressed by is equal to, is less than, or is the brother of)
>   that holds between an ordered pair of objects
>   -- (retrieved on Aug 15, 2011 @ 10:30am EST)

- [relationship](/questions/tagged/relationship) with 326 questions currently

[From Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/relationship): a noun --

> the state of being **related**
>   -- (retrieved on Aug 15, 2011 @ 10:30am EST)

---

Probable synonyms of [relation](/questions/tagged/relation):

- [relate](/questions/tagged/relate) 5 questions
- [related](/questions/tagged/related) 38 questions
- [relations](/questions/tagged/relations) 75 questions
- [relationships](/questions/tagged/relationships) 101 questions

A few tags *could* be synonyms, but I'm not sure.  As a statistician, I want to say these are a separate topic:

- [correlation](/questions/tagged/correlation) 94 questions
- [correlated](/questions/tagged/correlated) 14 questions

And a few tags which are close which **shouldn't** be synonyms:

- [relative](/questions/tagged/relative) 163 questions
- [relational](/questions/tagged/relational) 148 questions -- as in relational databases (which should also probably 
  be a synonym of [relational-database](/questions/tagged/relational-database) with 654 questions)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure the dictionary definition of the word matters much; IMO each tag should have a specific technical meaning or it becomes useless.

In this case, the common use of most of these tags is to express relations in a relational database. Whether we actually need a tag for the relations themselves is debatable, although we certainly don't need 6 different tags for the same concept.

[relate](/questions/tagged/relate) seems to be applicable to a specific software package (although perhaps the tag should be [relate+](/questions/tagged/relate%2b)) on one question, with the other 4 being the sort of "the word 'relate' appears in my question so I'll make it a tag for no apparent reason" tagging; in none of the questions is it taking about relations in the RDBMS sense.

[related](/questions/tagged/related) looks like a similarly useless tag, although in a couple of cases it could be changed to [relation](/questions/tagged/relation) meaningfully.

[relationships](/questions/tagged/relationships) is *mostly* a synonym in its usage, although there are cases where it's talking about OO inheritance rather than relations in a database.

[relations](/questions/tagged/relations) looks like a strict synonym, and with more usage than [relation](/questions/tagged/relation) may be a better fit as the main term.

[relative](/questions/tagged/relative) is completely unrelated, although it is itself ambiguous IMO.

Comment: I certainly agree about [tag:relate+], but I don't have the rep required (1500) to create it.

Answer (score 1):

[correlated](/questions/tagged/correlated) & [correlation](/questions/tagged/correlation) *could* be synonyms of [relation](/questions/tagged/relation):

- If two items are correlated, then a relation exists between them.

**However**

- *correlation* implies a bidirectional relationship whereas a [relation](/questions/tagged/relation) *could* be one direction.

So perhaps:  [bidirectional-relation](/questions/tagged/bidirectional-relation) (with 12 questions) & [correlated](/questions/tagged/correlated) -> [correlation](/questions/tagged/correlation)?